# Trying to upgrade the RAM in a Brother DCP-9055CDN printer but unclear on what the exact specs are for sourcing components

Tags: memory, printer

I would like to install additional memory in my printer, which is a [Brother DCP-9055CDN](https://support.brother.com/g/b/producttop.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp9055cdn_eu_as) and should take memory that conforms to:

- **Form Factor**: SO-DIMM
- **Type**: 144-pin and 16-bit output
- **CAS Latency**: 4
- **Clock Frequency**: 267 MHz (533 Mb/s/pin) or more
- **Capacity**: 64, 128 or 256 MB
- **DRAM Type**: DDR2 SDRAM

And so I bought something to match. It didn’t, though, because the notch didn’t line up with the socket.

[image]

Ok, my bad, I could probably have determined that from the product page at the online store.

Then I spent some more time searching, being extra mindful of the form factor, but then I came across [this](https://www.computersalg.dk/i/3546569/coreparts-ddr2-module-256-mb-so) (at over twice the cost), and the merchant has not responded to my queries about whether or not the product image is completely inaccurate:

[image]

I mean, seriously, that looks like an ancient form factor, possibly a "generic RAM stick" image. But I am now too uncertain about what to actually purchase that will for sure fit. A broader web search gives me products that are either *ludicrously* expensive brand-name items, or sold suspiciously cheaply by a Chinese supplier.

Any hints on where to buy legit, compatible memory — or, at least, which search terms to use — would be most welcome.

Comment: You bought a DDR3 SO-DIMM in stead of a DDR2. The notch is in a slightly different place. Otherwise they have the same formfactor. The 2nd picture is a standard DIMM (without the SO prefix). That won't fit. Please note: SO-DIMM come in 1.5V and 1.8V versions. The 1.5V version (usually indicated by a L somewhere in the typenumber) will work in a 1.8V slot, but not the other way around. Your printer can use the 1.5V version so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Adding RAM to a printer rarely helps anything. In most cases, it achieves nothing more than losing some money.

Answer (score 1):

Search term "DCP-9055CDN RAM" I found some for $18 from the States, though postage might be a bit expensive.

DDR2 **is** generally expensive for what it is these days. No-one makes it any more & hasn't for maybe a decade), which tends to make prices rise.

Your images - first is a SO-DIMM (**small outline** dual in-line memory module) but is DDR3, second is not a SO-DIMM - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM
*Late edit* You can get 144-pin SO-DIMMs, but they're quite rare, which is why I initially thought it was a regular DIMM. You want a 200-pin, though; similar form factor to your first image, but DDR2 is 200-pin, DDR3 is 204 pin (& the cutout is different).